# Can't create a user table through psql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a user table through `psql` in my command line, but I keep getting the error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"

This is the command I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE user (_id INTEGER, email VARCHAR password VARCHAR, score INTEGER)
```

I have seen that user is a reserved word, so I did try the follow variations of this command:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (_id INTEGER, email VARCHAR password, VARCHAR, score INTEGER)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE User (_id INTEGER, email VARCHAR, password, VARCHAR, score INTEGER)
```

But still get the same variation of the error.

I should note too, that this column did previously exist, but I could not edit it or do anything to it through my sql queries. I have also tested table creation that does in fact work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Remove extra comma on the example code, as pointed out by Kedar Limaye

Answer (score 1):

You missed to remove the comma after word password,here is the query

```
CREATE TABLE "User" (_id INTEGER, email VARCHAR, password VARCHAR, score INTEGER)
```

Comment: Good catch! Although that was a typo when I put the code here. The error is still happening even without the comma.

Comment: @theJuls- i have executed the query on sqlfiddle and it worked